# Chromium - Selective Cookie blocking doesn't work

Tags: windows, browser, privacy, chromium, cookies

I have a fresh install of Chromium Browser on Windows 7. Chromium Version 36.0.1926.0 (261698).

I got to Settings -> Privacy -> Clear Browsing Data .. & clear all cookies from from the beginning of time. Now if I go to 
Settings -> Privacy -> Content Settings ... -> All cookies and site data, I don't see any cookies.

In Settings -> Privacy -> Content Settings ... I set "Allow local data to be set".
I also go to Manage Exceptions and block the following sites from setting cookies.

[image: Block settings]

I then visit gmail.com (not even login, just visit the home page).

I go back to Cookies & Site data, I see cookies set by the sites I have asked Chromium to block

[image: Cookies!]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the patterns as `[*.]google.com` to catch references to sub-domains.

Source : 
 [Issue 90009: UI for entering hostname patterns in "Cookie and Site Data Exceptions" is unclear](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=90009).