# Chrome not blocking explicitly listed cookie from google

Tags: google-chrome, browser, cookies

For some reason, when I blacklist `[*.]google.com` in my Cookies exceptions, I still get a cookie from www.google.com in every session! Here is is the relevant entry in the exceptions screen:

[image: Cookie exceptions]

And here are my basic cookie settings:

[image: Cookie settings]

This blocks cookies when I'm actually *on* google.com, but I always get something set from `www.google.com` when I first start up the profile:

[image: www.google.com cookie]

I can manually delete it and it will stay deleted until I close and re-open Chrome. Is there a way to block this behavior? This is profile-specific, so I can't just block `www.google.com` at the router or firewall as far as I know (plus I may want to be able to access that site without it leaving any crumbs).

A similar question was raised [here](https://superuser.com/questions/737925/chromium-selective-cookie-blocking-doesnt-work), but that is just a problem with the domain pattern matching, which isn't the issue here.

Comment: Could it be that since Chrome is a Google (*Alphabet*) product, that it prevents blocking their own cookies?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Possibly, but I doubt it. It blocks cookies just fine if you go to www.google.com. Looking at the screenshot, I'm not even 100% sure that this is an actual cookie, per se, since the other entries actually say (n cookies).

Comment: What does "and site data" encompass? BTW, does Chrome use Adobe Flash cookies (which can be turned off in Flash)?